# sqlQuery of DocumentDB input bindings with modulation symbol makes function's failure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I using the DocumentDB input bindings on Azure Functions.

Today, I specified a following query as a sqlQuery.

```sql
SELECT c.id, c.created_at FROM c 
WHERE {epoch} - c.created_at_epoch >= 86400*31 
AND (CEILING({epoch}/86400) - CEILING(c.created_at_epoch / 86400)) % 31 = 0
```

Afterwards, I saw a following error when function is triggered.

```
2017-07-04T10:31:44.873 Function started (Id=95a2ab7a-8eb8-4568-b314-2c3b04a0eadf)
2017-07-04T10:31:49.544 Function completed (Failure, Id=95a2ab7a-8eb8-4568-b314-2c3b04a0eadf, Duration=4681ms)
2017-07-04T10:31:50.106 Exception while executing function: Functions.Bonus. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: The '%' at position 148 does not have a closing '%'.
```

I want to use a modulation symbol within sqlQuery. What can I?

Best regards.

---

2017-07-15(JST) Append.

And today, I tried following another query for avoid this issue.

```
SELECT c.id, c.created_at FROM c 
WHERE {epoch} - c.created_at_epoch >= 86400*31 AND 
(CEILING({epoch}/86400) - CEILING(c.created_at_epoch / 86400)) - 
(31 * 
    CEILING(
        (CEILING({epoch}/86400) - CEILING(c.created_at_epoch / 86400)) 
        / 31
    )
) = 0
```

Just in case, I tried this query that is specified a epoch = 1499218423 on the Cosmos DB.

```
SELECT c.id, c.created_at FROM c 
WHERE 1499218423 - c.created_at_epoch >= 86400*31 AND 
(CEILING(1499218423/86400) - CEILING(c.created_at_epoch / 86400)) - 
(31 * 
    CEILING(
        (CEILING(1499218423/86400) - CEILING(c.created_at_epoch / 86400))
        / 31
    )
) = 0
```

That's result is followings.

```
[
  {
    "id": "70251cbf-44b3-4cd9-991f-81127ad78bca",
    "created_at": "2017-05-11 18:46:16"
  },
  {
    "id": "0fa31de2-4832-49ea-a0c6-b517d64ede85",
    "created_at": "2017-05-11 18:48:22"
  },
  {
    "id": "b9959d15-92e7-41c3-8eff-718c4ab2be6e",
    "created_at": "2017-05-11 19:01:43"
  }
]
```

It looks fine. Then I specify it as sqlQuery and test with following queue data.

```
{"epoch":1499218423}
```

And code of the function is followings.

```
module.exports = function (context, myQueueItem) {
    context.log(context.bindings.members, myQueueItem);
    context.done();
};
```

Afetrwards, I saw following results.

```
2017-07-05T03:00:47.158 Function started (Id=e4d060b5-3ddc-4271-bf91-9f314e7e1148)
2017-07-05T03:00:47.408 [] { epoch: 1499871600 }
2017-07-05T03:00:47.408 Function completed (Success, Id=e4d060b5-3ddc-4271-bf91-9f314e7e1148, Duration=245ms)
```

It looks differences in results of bindings(as context.bindings.members).

Why appeared this differences?

Related question : [Deferences among the Azure CosmosDB Query Explorer's results and the Azure Functions results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916811/deferences-among-the-azure-cosmosdb-query-explorers-results-and-the-azure-funct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to use a modulation symbol within sqlQuery. What can I?

The modulation symbol(%) in Azure function configuration is used to retrieve values from app settings. For your issue, I suggest you add a item in app setting as following.

[image]

After that, you could use %modulationsymbol% instead of % in your query as following.

```
SELECT c.id, c.created_at FROM c 
WHERE {epoch} - c.created_at_epoch >= 86400*31 
AND (CEILING({epoch}/86400) - CEILING(c.created_at_epoch / 86400)) %modulationsymbol% 31 = 0
```

Comment: I tried it, and error is resolved. But differences is appeared among CosmosDB query explorer's results and Azure Functions results. I'm going to create an another question about this deferences. Thank you.

Comment: I created another question about this differences. [Deferences among the Azure CosmosDB Query Explorer's results and the Azure Functions results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44903632/sqlquery-of-documentdb-input-bindings-with-modulation-symbol-makes-functions-fa)