# Azure Cosmos DB convert string to int

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am having json data in Azure cosmos DB and want to convert the string data in number format.
I tried with toint() method but it won't work.
is there any method like convet(int,"3") like sql please share.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Query DocumentDB in Azure Functions by an integer not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529125/sql-query-documentdb-in-azure-functions-by-an-integer-not-working)

Answer (score 3):

Update - now this is a built-in function (maybe always was? don't know):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-stringtonumber

This answer showed up as #1 on Google, so figured I'd correct it.

Answer (score 0):

CosmosDB supports UDFs in javascript. You can simply create a UDF that will use the `parseInt()` javascript function and convert the string to and int.

Your UDF would look like this:

```
function convertToInt(strNum) {
    return parseInt(strNum);
};
```

Then simply use this udf in your query like this:

`SELECT udf.convertToInt(c.age) FROM c`

You can read more about that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-sql-query#UserDefinedFunctions