# OFFSET and LIMIT are not working when placed in CosmosDB binding of Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have followed the process mentioned in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916811/difference-among-the-azure-cosmosdb-query-explorers-results-and-the-azure-funct) to supply values for OFFSET and LIMIT in my sqlquery. Below is how it looks like

SELECT * FROM c where c.recordType = 'employees' OFFSET udf.convertToNumber('0') LIMIT udf.convertToNumber('200')

But facing this error,
"message\":\"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'udf'.\"

Any help, please?

Comment: Can you execute this query correctly in the Azure Portal?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't apply just the OFFSET 0 LIMIT 200, instead of calling a udf to convert the string 0 to number 0 and string 200 to number 200?

Comment: Also, I think you can't even use udfs as arguments for the OFFSET and LIMIT, since these operations are expecting a number, and not a function that returns something (because it does not know if returns a number of not) when evaluating the syntax of your query.